# SQL Server Driver compatible with Async

Tags: python, sql-server, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

Using the API CCXT I am pulling the orderbook for multiple symbols using async, this is an example provided by the API themselves and I have tweaked it to my requirements.

However, sometimes when I am running the program I find that some symbols do not download, after speaking to CCXT they advised that it is most likely due to the fact I am writing to the SQL Server table in a way that isn't compatible with async, meaning I need a driver that works with async. Below is my current code that works but misses some symbols sometimes.

```
import ccxt.async_support as ccxt
from asyncio import gather, run
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine


async def symbol_loop(exchange, symbol):
    print('Connecting to Database Server')
    params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};"
                                     "SERVER=PC;"
                                     "DATABASE=crypto;"
                                     'UID=abc;'
                                     'PWD=123;'
                                     "Trusted_Connection=yes")
    engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))

    print('Starting the', exchange.id, 'symbol loop with', symbol)
    level = 0
    while True:
        try:
            level += 1
            orderbook = await exchange.fetch_order_book(symbol, 5)
            now = exchange.milliseconds()
            print(exchange.iso8601(now), exchange.id, symbol, orderbook['asks'][0], len(orderbook['asks']),
                  orderbook['bids'][0], len(orderbook['bids']))

            # Create DataFrame
            orderbook_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1))
            # Clean Symbol
            clean_symbol = symbol.replace('USD_PERP', '/USD')
            # Add Unique Identifier - Symbol+Exchange
            orderbook_df['ID'] = f'{clean_symbol}_BINANCEFUTURES'
            # Add Loop Level
            orderbook_df['Level'] = level
            # Add Date/Time
            orderbook_df['DateTime'] = datetime.now()
            # Add Ticker Symbol
            orderbook_df['Symbol'] = str(symbol)
            # Add Exchange
            orderbook_df['Exchange'] = str(exchange)
            # Add Bid Levels
            orderbook_df['Bid1'] = orderbook['bids'][0][0]
            # Add Ask Levels
            orderbook_df['Ask1'] = orderbook['asks'][0][0]
            # Add Bid Volume Levels
            orderbook_df['BidVol1'] = orderbook['bids'][0][1]
            # Add Ask Volume Levels
            orderbook_df['AskVol1'] = orderbook['asks'][0][1]
            # Add Trading Fee
            orderbook_df['Fee'] = 0.2

            orderbook_df.to_sql("Historical_Crypto", engine, if_exists='append')


        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            raise e  # uncomment to break all loops in case of an error in any one of them
            # break  # you can break just this one loop if it fails


async def exchange_loop(exchange_id, symbols):
    print('Starting the', exchange_id, 'exchange loop with', symbols)
    exchange = getattr(ccxt, exchange_id)()
    loops = [symbol_loop(exchange, symbol) for symbol in symbols]
    await gather(*loops)
    await exchange.close()


async def main():
    exchanges = {
        'binancecoinm': ['ADAUSD_PERP', 'AVAXUSD_PERP', 'BCHUSD_PERP', 'BNBUSD_PERP', 'BTCUSD_PERP', 'DOGEUSD_PERP'],
    }
    loops = [exchange_loop(exchange_id, symbols) for exchange_id, symbols in exchanges.items()]
    await gather(*loops)


run(main())
```

I was hoping someone might have an idea of how to replace how I write to SQL in a way that is compatible with async. I have looked at SQLAlchemy and tried their example but I could not get it to work, maybe I missed something.

I am hoping it is an easy fix and someone has a simple solution.

The line that causes the issue is `orderbook_df.to_sql("Historical_Crypto", engine, if_exists='append')` so this is what needs to be replicated in some way that is asynchronous.

Comment: `DRIVER={SQL Server};` is for using the (very) old original ODBC drivers. If you haven't already have you tried to download and install [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) and then use `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};` in your connection string instead?